# Session variable set in home controller not available in other controller + C#

Tags: c#, session, session-variables

My Application uses C# + Angular 4.0.
I need to set value in a session variable to save user roles which is done in the Home Controller, and then I need to access this session variable in another controller. On doing so I get null in the session variable.

I have a MVC C# application using Angular 4.0.
I am able to save my session variables in my Home controller, but when I try and access it in another controller (for another page), it return null (null exception) and I cannot use it anywhere else.
What am I missing?

```
//Home Controller
DataSet dsGroupPermission = new DataSet();

dsGroupPermission = authorizeUser(strGroupResult);

if (dsGroupPermission.Tables.Count > 0 && 
    sGroupPermission.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Dataset"] = dsGroupPermission;
    strUserStatus = "ValidUser";
}

//Another Controller
DataSet dspermission = new DataSet();
dspermission = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Dataset"];
```

I expect the above Session variable Dataset to store a Table which shows the authorization for a user to add, update or delete for each page and retrieve the same back in any other controller.

Comment: Frame challenge: you should be using bearer tokens for this

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the session variable like :

```
//Another Controller
DataSet dspermission = new DataSet();
dspermission = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Dataset"] as DataSet;
```

Comment: Well the session variable is gone when I reach the other controllers. So that does not help. I think this is something to do with the way Angular handles sessions.